# Textbox for Decimal value null when submitting form in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, razor

Textbox value when submitting the form is null in the controller.  Simplified structure of what I have is below:

**MODEL**

```
public class MyObject
{
    public decimal? DecimalProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@model List<MyObject>

@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
{
   using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateObject", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
   {
      @Html.Textbox(String.Format("Model[{0}].DecimalProperty", i), Model[i].DecimalProperty)
      <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
   }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult UpdateObject(MyObject myObject)
{
   // Do Stuff...
}
```

If I put a breakpoint in the controller method, then check the property values of myObject, the DecimalProperty is null.  There are other properties on the actual object I'm using and those come across alright, but for some reason this property isn't.  I haven't found anything that suggests that decimals must be handled differently than a DateTime or string.  I have also tried writing out the html for the input by hand:

```
 <input type="text" name="@(String.Format("Model[{0}].DecimalProperty", i))" value="@Model[i].DecimalProperty" />
```

I have set the *name* and the *id* attributes of the textbox just to be on the safe side.  Any ideas as to why my textbox value is null when I submit the form?

Setting the [HttpPost] attribute does not help.

Comment: You seen to have a list of models, why is that? If you have an enumerator on the view but only one object on the action, I'm not sure if the model binder will figure out what to do.

Comment: On the view my model is a list of objects.  There are also multiple forms on the view (one for each object). Model[i] represents that specific element in the model.

Comment: Edited that into the view code block.

Comment: Try "decimal?"  You have to account for the possible null value.

Comment: But if I put a value in the textbox, it shouldn't be null in the controller when I submit the form.  But yes, the property is actually a decimal? I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you add the [HttpPost] attribute to the controller method? (You may have done that, can't see from your code example)

Comment: @Nick but your action model does expect a list, so the index in `[n]` won't help. Actually, it is breaking the model binding.

Comment: @Matt That didn't work either.

Comment: @AndreCalil The controller method does not expect a list, the first parameter is MyObject myObject.  The other properties on the object being passed across to the controller method are correct, it's just this particular property that is not being brought across.

Comment: @Nick can you post the rest of your view code? At least those properties that are working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your action signature.
You should change it to accept whole list of models, or change Html.TextBox's Name attribute equal to property name of MyObject, cause default MVC binder cannot map it correctly.

So, first option:

```
public ActionResult UpdateObject(List<MyObject> myObject)
{
   // Do Stuff...
}
```

Second option:

```
@Html.Textbox("DecimalProperty", Model[i].DecimalProperty)
```

Comment: I actually JUST tried that (removing the Model[i] from the textbox name) and it worked.  Awesome!

Comment: @Nick that's what I've been telling you :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand what you were saying in the earlier comments, @AndreCalil.  That was my failure.

Comment: @Nick or I wasn't explaining correctly :) anyway, glad it is working now